# Minimum Cost to split a island by making a horizontal cut or a vertical cut

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Divide an island which is in the form of **N * M** matrix into pieces of **1 * 1** matrices. You can do the splitting of the island by making a horizontal cut or a vertical cut. In each case the island gets divided into 2 pieces. There are certain coins in each cell. The cost of split is the sum of all the cells in the island which is to be split.

Problem is to split the island in minimum cost.

**Input Format**:
First line contains 2 integers **N**  and **M**

Then N lines follow each containing **M** integers.

**Output Format:**

Print the minimum cost required.

```
Sample Input:                             Sample Output:
2 2                                       16
2 2
1 3
```

I am looking for a approach to solve this problem.

Comment: can u share an example input that is of size n = 4 ? It will provide me better understanding to write an algorithm for the above question

Answer (score 0):

@zenwraight

Algorithm :-

Take a n*m coin matrix as input arr[n][m]
Create Sum matrix for rows and columns - sum_row[n] and sum_col[m]
and total_sum 
func(arr[n][m])---->Cut horizontally after first row then we get a matrices of arr[n-1][m] and arr[1][m].Cost is cost total_sum
Now break arr[1][m] each element vertically - sum_row[0]+cost(arr[1][m-1]) and soon until all first_row elements become unit matrices.
func(arr[n-1][m])

Comment: Do u have the link to this problem, so I can submit my algorithm and test it and see if it fails for any corner cases

Comment: Actually i saw this question in a hiring in hackerearth , now this question is unavailable for checking.

Comment: Got it, but did u understand my approach ?

Comment: Yes ,I understood ur approach @zenwraight ,I tried and compiled using ur approach during the hiring but i got all wrong outputs .Then i realized that the matrix it is taking input is money matrix in which each element is cost of each unit matrix,thats how i changed my approach after the hiring test.

Answer (score -1):

@zenwraight  Explanation for above sample input and output:

First we split the matrix with cost 8 and get 2 matrices as (2,2) and (1,3).

Now we can split (2,2) with cost 4 into (2) and (2).

Now we can split (1,3) with cost 4 into (1) and (3).

Comment: Ya that I understood, I just want to know do u have a test case with n > 2 and what would be it's output, in order to validate my algorithm. That way I will be sure that my algorithm is correct

Comment: u can have this in the comment, it's not an answer, so u shouldn't post here

Comment: okkk thanks ,I am new to this .As my reputation score was too low ,I was unable to post a comment. @zenwraight

Comment: got u makes sense, now do u have an example for a n > 2 and what the output should be ? I will post the answer as soon as i get another sample input and output to verify my algorithm. Thanks

Comment: no @zenwraight I am even searching for that.Can u explain your algo for n=2,may I  get to know for n>2

Comment: I have posted an answer above, have a look